# How to make an iOS Drop down menu

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu

How do I create a good looking drop down menu in iOS. It should open when the user clicks a button in the navigation bar.

I tried creating a table, but got the error Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances. If I use UITableViewController, then it has to be full width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try using a CollectionView instead of TableView, and if you need sopport for iOS 4+, PSTCollectionView is a good option :)

Answer (score 1):

What I did is added a Button and on button tap one table view is shown, whenever any row is selected that row title is set to button title.

```
- (void)addOrganizationButton {

self.organizationButton =  [UIUtils createButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(203,115,451,38)
                     titleText:@"Organization"
                          type:UIButtonTypeCustom
                   normalImage:nil selectedImage:nil
                        target:self
                          view:self.registerView
                           tag:0
                      selector:@selector(organizationButtonTap)];
self.organizationButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
[self.organizationButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.organizationButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
self.organizationButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
}
```

//Show table view on button tap

```
- (void)organizationButtonTap {
self.organizationTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(203,153, 451,220)];
self.organizationTable.layer.borderWidth = 1;
self.organizationTable.dataSource = self;
self.organizationTable.delegate = self;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frame = self.organizationTable.frame;
                     frame.size.height = 220;
                     self.organizationTable.frame = frame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];

[self.registerView addSubview:self.organizationTable];
}
```

//Table view delegates

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

return 1;//to be changed
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return 3;//get dictionary count
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
      cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell;
NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell Identifier";
cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil){

    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}


cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                       @"Section %ld, Cell %ld",
                       (long)indexPath.section,
                       (long)indexPath.row];
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


[self.organizationButton setTitle:@"faf" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0.0
                    options:  UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frame = self.organizationTable.frame;
                     frame.size.height = 0;
                     self.organizationTable.frame = frame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a custom view for that and add it as a subview in your ViewController. 
Use UIView animations for simulating "drop down" effect.